# Como saber as fontes suportadas pelo commonality.cloud?

Tags: r, wordcloud

Gostaria de saber quais são as fontes suportadas seja pelo wordcloud ou commonality.cloud.

Importei algumas fontes com o pacote abaixo mas muitas delas não funcionam.

```
install.packages("extrafont")
library(extrafont)
font_import()
```

Abaixo segue um exemplo de código para a nuvem de palavras.

```
commonality.cloud(mydata, 
                  colors = "black", 
                  scale= c(32,4) ,
                  random.order=FALSE,
                  vfont=c("Fontes_suportadas","plain"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As únicas fontes suportadas pelo `commonality.cloud` (assim como as wordclouds) são as fontes da família Hershey, que tem como principal vantagem o fato de cada caractere ser descrito como um conjunto de pontos (são as fontes vetoriais), e renderizar este caractere significa juntar estes pontos com uma linha. Com isso, evitamos o problema de tamanho (como é vetorial não existe o efeito de pixelização) e ao plotar um caractere rotacionado a aparência fica melhor.

Os seguintes typefaces e fontindex são suportados:

- typeface: 'serif' | fontindex: {'plain', 'italic', 'bold', 'bold italic', 'cyrillic', 'oblique cyrillic', 'EUC'}
- typeface: 'sans serif' | fontindex: {'plain', 'italic', 'bold', 'bold italic'}
- typeface: 'script' | fontindex: {'plain', 'italic', 'bold'}
- typeface: 'gothic english' | fontindex: {'plain'}
- typeface: 'gothic german' | fontindex: {'plain'}
- typeface: 'gothic italian' | fontindex: {'plain'}
- typeface: 'serif symbol' | fontindex: {'plain', 'italic', 'bold'}
- typeface: 'sans serif symbol' | fontindex: {'plain', 'italic'}

Exemplo:

```
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)

data(SOTU)
corp <- SOTU

term.matrix <- TermDocumentMatrix(corp)
term.matrix <- as.matrix(term.matrix)
commonality.cloud(term.matrix, 
                  colors = "black", 
                  scale= c(32,4) ,
                  random.order=FALSE,
                  vfont=c("sans serif","plain"))
```

Para mais informações, `?Hershey`

Comment: Incrível resposta. Muito obrigado!